# Calculate Pace To String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am trying to calculate pace (min/mi) and format it as mmmm:ss.

So far I calculate my pace into a float by taking 60 and dividing it by my average speed. At an average speed of 76mph, my average pace is displayed as 0.79. I want to format it so that it converts my 0.79 minutes to mmmm:ss (thus showing my average pace as 0000:47). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double milesPerHour = 76.0;
int secondsPerMile = (int)round(3600.0 / milesPerHour);
NSString *paceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d:%02d", secondsPerMile / 60, secondsPerMile % 60];
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I think it would help if you gave an explanation too, no?

Comment: I don't find anything confusing at all, but I think it would help if James learned what the format specifier meant. You know, the whole "give a man a fish" adage.

Comment: I still haven't received a fish! :D

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question right, but this is pretty much just math. 
You can get the minutes by rounding your value (0.79 in this case) down and you can get seconds by taking your value, subtracting the minutes from it and multiplying that by 60.

So if you'd need 2.35 minutes for a mile, you'd have 2 minutes and 0.35*60 = 21 seconds.